# Какая ошибка в этом коде

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] wordListOne = {"Мама"};
    String[] wordListTwo = {"Мыла"};
    String[] wordListThree = {"Раму"};
    
    int oneLength = wordListOne.lenght;
    int twoLength = wordListTwo.lenght;
    int threeLength = wordListThree.lenght;
    
    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
    int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);
    
    String phrase = wordListOne[rand1]+wordListTwo[rand2]+wordListThree[rand3];
    
    System.out.println(phrase);
}
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вас надо спросить какая тут ошибка в коде

Comment: Установили бы IDE и таких вопросов не возникало бы.

Comment: @afjord, так вроде и так понятно написано. И какие там IDE для телефона сейчас популярны?

Comment: @Qwertiy про IDE писал до скриншота. На чём с телефона пишут не знаю, да и не хотелось бы это знать:)

Answer (score 2):

Везде заменить `lenght` ↔ `length`

Comment: Вы опечатались:) `lenght` → `length`

Comment: @afjord yep) спс)